# apply function in specific range in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my input:

```
index frame user1   user2
    0   0   0       0
    1   1   0       0
    2   2   0       0
    3   3   0       0
    4   4   0       0
    5   5   0       0
```

Also I have two objects `start_frame` and `end_frame` - pandas Series look like this for 'start frame' :

```
index   frame
3        3
```

and for `end frame`:

```
   index    frame
    4       5
```

My problem is apply function in specific column - `user1` and in specific row number, where values I get from `start_frame` and `end_frame`.
I expect output like this:

```
 frame  user1   user2
0   0   0       0
1   1   0       0
2   2   0       0
3   3   1       0
4   4   1       0
5   5   1       0
```

I trying this but it return all column to ones or any other output but not that I want

```
def my_func(x):    
       x=x+1
       return x
df['user1']=df['user1'].between(df['frame']==3, df['frame']==5, inclusive=False).apply(lambda x: add_one(x))
```

I trying another code:

```
df['user1']=df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['frame'] in (3,5) else 0, axis=1)
```

But it return only 1 in row 3 and 5, how here in `(3,5)`  insert range?

So I have two question: First and most important how to apply `my_func` exacly in rows what I need, and other question how to use my object `end_frame` and `start_frame` instead manually insert in function.
Thank you

Updated:

```
arr_rang = range(3,6)

df['user1']=df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['frame'] in (arr_rang) else 0, axis=1)
```

Now it's return 1 in frame 3,4,5. That I need. But still I dont understand how use my objects `end_frame` and `start_frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's append start_frame and end_frame since they are having common columns then check values using `isin()` and finally changing value by using boolean masking and `loc` accessor:

```
s=start_frame.append(end_frame)
mask=(df['index'].isin(s['index'])) | (df['frame'].isin(s['frame']))
df.loc[mask,'user1']=df.loc[mask,'user1']+1
#you can also use np.where() in place of loc accessor
```

output of `df`:

```
  index     frame   user1   user2
0   0       0       0       0
1   1       1       0       0
2   2       2       0       0
3   3       3       1       0
4   4       4       1       0
5   5       5       1       0
```

**Update:**

use:

```
mask=df['frame'].between(3,5)
df.loc[mask,'user1']=df.loc[mask,'user1']+1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but its still don't run from 3 to 5, it's puts 1 only in 3 and 5 frame, not between [3:5], so frame 4 still with 0 value

Comment: @TeoK updated answer...kindly have a look

Comment: @TeoK also in previous method it runs  from 3 to 5 ,because of index=4 in end_frame

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```py
def putHello(row):
  row["hello"] = "world"
  return row

data.iloc[5:7].apply(putHello,axis=1)
```

The output would look something like this
[image]

The documentation for pandas functions

- [Iloc pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
- [Apply pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: but I need to apply  and return func in same dataframe, not slicer

Comment: You can try that without iloc too. Can you try something like `data.apply(putHello,axis=1)`